# Regex in python for time format followed by comma and three digits

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a file with thousands of time formats. Some of them are in their standard formats, while others are followed by a comma and three digits like this:

```
    Standard format: 00:00:44
    Followed by comma and three digits: 00:00:46,235
```

I've removed the standard formats using the following regex:

```
   text = re.sub(r'^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$)', '', text)
```

And that is ok. But for the time format followed by comma and three digits nothing that I've tried so far has helped me to remove them. Please, how can I remove this odd time format pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches the standard time format.

```
r'^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$)'
```

Just add the comma part at the end, and make it optional.

```
r'^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d(?:,\d{3})?$)'
```

Explanation for `(?:,\d{3})?`:

```
(?:      )     Non-capturing group
   ,\d{3}      Comma, then three digits
          ?    Match zero or one times
```

Comment: Thank you, @Pranav, your regex resolved both time formats at once. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, @Pranav! Really very very helpful!!

Comment: @CygnusX-1 no worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way is to use `split()`:

```
text = text.split(",")[0]
text = re.sub(r'^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$)', '', text)
```

You can also update your regex to use add an optional part at the end.

```
text = re.sub(r'^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d),?\d{0,3}$', '', text)
```

Comment: In [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) (and [IRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)) seconds can start with a `6`.

Comment: Thank you @Nathaniel.

Comment: @KlausD That is valid, though maybe a better comment for the OP? Though, without more context (where are these numbers coming from? Is the regex serving to filter bad data?) I'd be hard pressed to determine whether to include that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.sub`:

```py
inp = "Followed by comma and three digits: 00:00:46,235"
output = re.sub(r'\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),\d{3}', r'\1', inp)
print(output)  # Followed by comma and three digits: 00:00:46
```

Comment: Thank you, @Tim.